# Which UI Elements are used for table-like looks? (ios)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am wondering how to make views like the on here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/FeedbackCommunication.html

Is this just an UITableView or are other UI elemets used for this look?

If it is a table view, are all the cells custom cells? How do i get those empty cells like between "Scheduled" and "Allow Calls From"?

Comment: It is just tableview with footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tableview. I would assume the "empty cells" are the same as the ones with text, but height is calculated based on the text. 
So if there's no text, there's a default value + 0 as height.

If they aren't custom cells, then they are section footers.

Answer (score 0):

It is an UITableView with section footers. The cells are custom, you can easily recreate those with dropping a UISwitch in it for "Scheduled" and another label for "Allow Calls From". You can then segue to another View Controller from "Allow Calls From". Basically this is very easy to recreate.